# Connecting Berkely DB in java through sqlitejdbc-v056.jar

Tags: java

i am connecting berkely database through sqlitejdbc-v056.jar & i got the following error and not performing insert ,update ,delete opration

```
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
        at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
        at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
        at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:102)
        at testdb.TestProgram.main(TestProgram.java:37)
```

download jar from following link http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

i am using following code for performing

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import org.sqlite.*;

/**
 *
 * @author dhananjay.joshi
 */
public class TestProgram
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Connection con=null;
        Statement smt=null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            System.out.print("Connnection req");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Prog\\Emp.db");
            smt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("\n Connected");
            String que = "insert into student values(2,'kiran')";
            smt.executeUpdate("insert into student values(2,'kiran');");
            System.out.print("Insert Data");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to BerkeleyDB with a sql lite jdbc driver? That's just nuts!

Comment: @luis.espinal - not totally nuts: http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/063695

Comment: Damn, I stand corrected then.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a light weight SQL database. Berkley-DB is not an SQL database. They both have nothing to do with each other.

If you want to read/write a Berkley DB file you need a jar file with the helper classes for Berkley-DB.

A [google search for berkeley db java](http://www.google.de/search?q=berkley+db+java#hl=en&pwst=1&sa=X&ei=kPzxTfGCKtHKswaRlbmHBw&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=berkeley+db+java&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d3b1dd5fceae043c&biw=950&bih=693) should help you.

Comment: And make a back up of your db file ... you easy could have wrecked it with your first atempt.

Comment: oops, I stand corrected. Oracle has bought berkeley DB and *is indeed* providing an SQLite (3) access layer to it.